# adding weekdays - clears the time

Tags: php

I've tired to add 10 weekdays to now. Everything is OK, but it clears the time part. Do you know why?

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $now.'<br>';
$mod = strtotime($now." +10 weekdays");
echo $mod.'<br>';
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$mod).'<br>';
```

Output:

```
2011-05-23 14:34:02
1307311200
2011-06-06 00:00:00
```

My expected output were:

```
 2011-06-06 14:34:02
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using PHP 5.3.6? There appears to be a bug introduced in that version which zeroes the time values.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.2.6. Not the newest.

Comment: Ahh, your code produces the same (unexpected) behaviour in all versions, 5.2.0 onwards.  As Pekka mentioned, you can just move the location of the relative date part (`+10 weekdays`) to before the absolute part (`$now`).  This has been a part of PHP for so long now that I'm not sure whether it's a "bug" or a "feature" but is certainly unexpected as all relative parts are processed after non-relative parts (unless documented otherwise).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a difference in interpretation.

You could do the following to enforce the time:

```
<?php

$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("H:i:s");
echo $date.' '.$time.'<br>';
$mod= strtotime($date." +10 weekdays $time");
echo $mod.'<br>';
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$mod).'<br>';
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. (I still don't understand why "+n weekdays" does not produce this output...)

Answer (score -2):

There are several examples on the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php) which can help you add days while still preserving the times.

Comment: I don't think `DateTime::add()` can do weekdays